# SDL Tridion Character Limit increase on Keywords' Description Field

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, keyword

My authoring team gets the below error and they want to increase the character limit on Keywords' `Description Field`.

> Invalid value for property 'Description'. The length of the Description property for the object of type 'Keyword' with title 'must be between 1 and 255 characters.

*Looking for good solution using gui extension....*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK: It's not possible to extend Keyword description field size it's tied with Database ITEM table Description field size, currently, it's designed to allow 255 characters only.

If you're looking to keep bigger description content on a keyword level. you could create a metadata schema with a custom description field as a text field or RTF field depends on your business requirement.

To get those values on the web app side either do it on the Content Manager side custom JSON template to read and publish as JSON, or you could publish that category and access using CIL on website.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 5):

It's true - you can't extend it as per Velmurugan states.

I can't suggest an alternative for your web app purposes as it's not clear what you're using the description for but I would add:

If you **translate keywords** the translation will **not** be imported if the translated value is over 255 characters; so 'fixing' this with a GUI extension may not suffice.

If there's not a simple work-around (e.g. you are already populating controls from specific categories and can't change the app etc.), I would strongly consider using something such as metadata for the full value and the 'description' as a short summary.

Answer (score 3):

Besides everything Dylan and Velu stated which is all true, I would like to ask why are you trying to store more than 256 characters in keyword description? Taxonomies are meant to be used to tag/classify content, not to be content themselves. Just like tags on social networks :) they should describe your content, not be content. If you have keywords that have 2 full sentences and exceed this, then you should rethink your content modeling strategy, not do crazy hacks (which we all love).